# how to play an audio in background when the tableview cells are clicked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

i have tableview where i am displaying my .wav files  of resources folder in tableview . The songs are displayed properly in tableview .When i select a particular song in tableview cell on that particular song a checkmark is shown and at the same time the song should be played on background .i have done this code to play the particular selected song on background but it does not work properly.What may be the problem.Thanks.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    app = (StopSnoozeAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    app.newcheckarray = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathsForResourcesOfType:@".wav" inDirectory:nil]retain];
    tblView.delegate = self;
    tblView.dataSource = self;


}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }



    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            soundstring = [app.newcheckarray objectAtIndex:0];
            cell.textLabel.text = [soundstring lastPathComponent];

            break;
        case 1:
            soundstring  =[app.newcheckarray objectAtIndex:1];
            cell.textLabel.text = [soundstring  lastPathComponent];
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
    cell.accessoryType = ([indexPath isEqual:rowselection]) ? UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    return cell;
}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.rowselection = indexPath;

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    [tableView reloadData];

    for (int i= 0;i <[[self.navigationController viewControllers] count];++i)
    {
        UIViewController *aController = [[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([aController isKindOfClass:[TAddAlarmController class]])
        {
            NSString *newsong1 = [app.newcheckarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            app.newsong = [newsong1 lastPathComponent];
            NSURL *pewPewURL1 = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:app.newsong];
            AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:pewPewURL1 error:nil];

            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
            [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

            [audioPlayer play];         
            [delegate selectsoundControllerReturnedsound:app.newsong forIndexPath:self.indexPathToChange];

        }


    }


}
```

in the didselect i am initialising my audioplayer but it does not play the audio.

Answer (score 0):

I have used below code for UIAlertView. You can try it in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

method

you need to add `AudioToolbox.framework` and

```
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioServices.h>
```

Code :

```
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Voicemail" ofType:@"wav"];       
    SystemSoundID soundID;      
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath: soundPath], &soundID);       
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
```

Comment: i have done this code but the problem is soundID always returns 0

Comment: you can refer http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/ipad-development/playing-audio-file-in-ipad/